# How to add a column in dataframe

Tags: casting, row, mean, addition

I casted a dataframe using reshape package that is 100 obs by 1000 variables with some NA's. How would I add a column that includes mean, median, min, max, total etc... to the data frame?

I keep getting "length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent" error.. when trying apply function and simple rowMeans functions..

Thanks!

Comment: i.e. df1$mean <- apply(df1, 1, function(x){mean(x)})is giving the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try using `reshape2::dcast` instead of `reshape::cast` to cast your dataframe and then run the following:

```
df1$mean<-apply(df1,1,function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Comment: thanks this worked! just have a question now to add 'count'.. thought df1$count <- apply(df1,1,function(x) count(x, na.rm=TRUE)) would work but it gives unused argument. when i try removing the na.rm it just gives string. basically, if there is a 4x4 data frame where the 5th column would represent "count", and there are some NA's in the first through 4th cols

Comment: please add it as a separate question with the code you tried and expected output.